# Troubles Overwritting Wordpress Url Rewrites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

so essentially right now I have a plugin enabled to allow me to use php in my pages. I've setup a page and set the permalink as the homepage. Doing this I'm able to make requests like

```
http://mysite.com/?profile=Rihanna
```

and the php code will execute based on the given artist.

The issue appears when I try to make this url more seo friendly, I add the following rewrite rule to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^artist/(.*).html http://mysite.com/?profile=$1
```

thinking that it should work but it does not, it simply goes to the wordpress 404 page. Now if I redirect it to a regular html file instead of mysite.com/?profile=$1 it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong and how I can get it working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your rule is **before** all of your wordpress rules. Wordpress' rules route all requests through am `index.php` and since "artist" is probably a bad permalink, it'll return a 404.

Additionally, if you include the `http://mysite.com` in your rule's target, it will inherently redirect the browser as opposed to internally rewriting the URI. You should remove it and include an `[L]` flag so rewriting stops in the current iteration (thus the wordpress rules won't get applied):

```
RewriteRule ^artist/(.*).html /?profile=$1 [L]
```